# Erro ao utilizar a biblioteca urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, osx, urllib

estou tentando fazer uma simples aplicação `Hello World` dando uma olhada na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html) com a biblioteca `urllib` com objetivo de pegar um conteúdo de um site em específico.

Farei o refinamento para o conteúdo que desejo posteriormente.

Estou tentando rodar o seguinte código:

```
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
    html = response.read()
```

E está apresentando o seguinte problema:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scapy_articles.py", line 3, in <module>
    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)>
```

Alguém poderia me auxiliar na resolução deste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que os certificados não são mais instalados automaticamente no Mac, você precisa instalá-los.

Rode o seguinte comando para instalar os certificados:

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Uma outra forma é ignorar o certificado, para ignorar ficaria assim:

```
import ssl
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/', context=context) as response:
    html = response.read()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @nosklo, executando o comando ```/Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command``` consegui rodar o código e obter o resultado esperado.

Comment: Coloquei a tag OSX na pergunta, já que o problema nesse caso está intimamente ligado as configurações nesse sistema. Esse erro também pode ocorrer se o programa estiver atrás de um proxy configurado incorretamente (efetivamente sendo um man-in-the-middle) , nesse caso, só colocando opções no código e ambiente para ignorar os certificados.

Comment: Tudo bem @jsbueno, obrigado pela colaboração.